# Regex matching of range with pre-defined labels

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex that allows any number (x), or comma separated numbers (x,x), or any range (x-x) for an input on my page:

`^\d+(?:(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?|(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*)$`

This works perfectly but I have a new requirement. I need to allow the user to label what they are defining and allow that if it's valid. For example, they can say: `Buildings: 1000-1010` or `Buildings: 1001,1002`.

`Buildings:` must be in the beginning of the string followed a colon followed by the rest. If they don't specify I won't know what they are saying.

Currently Buildings is the only label they can define, but I know more will be coming so I would also like to be able to specify that, if possible. But hopefully I can figure it out if I figure out how to allow one:

```
let input = 'Buildings: 1000-1001';
/^\d+(?:(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?|(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*\s*,?)$/.test(input); // should be ok

input = 'Buildings: 1000';
/^\d+(?:(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?|(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*\s*,?)$/.test(input); // should be ok

input = 'Buildings: 1000,2002';
/^\d+(?:(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?|(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*\s*,?)$/.test(input); // should be ok
```

For future, say I have an array of labels:

```
 const categories: ['Buildings', 'Cars', 'Houses'];
```

To loop over this list and run the test and include the variable's value in the regex. Is it possible?

Are you supposed to hardcode the text? I started trying that but I kept getting errors.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the labels do not contain any special regex meta character, you might shorten the pattern and use an alternation

```
^(?:Buildings|Cars|Houses):\s*\d+(?:\s*[-,]\s*\d+)*$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kMkkv1/1).

```js
const categories = ['Buildings', 'Cars', 'Houses'];
const regex = new RegExp(`^(?:${categories.join("|")}):\\s*\\d+(?:\\s*[-,]\\s*\\d+)*$`);

[
  "Buildings: 1000-1001",
  "Buildings: 1000",
  "Buildings: 1000,2002",
  "Test: 1000,2002"
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`));
```

Comment: This works great. But I realize now I have different requirements for each category. Actually, I only really need two regexes. One is what you helped with for numbers/range. The other is one that will allow any text after the identifier as long as it is comma separated (so I can split them to array). How does this need to change for [a-z] or any comma sep text? Your help is immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler regex should do the trick along with some format strings.

for example a simpler regex like `/\d+?([,-]\d+?)*?$/` should do fine matching all three of your examples.

And for the string substitution using the `new RegExp` syntax will allow you to use standard format strings.

For Example:

```js
const categories = ['Buildings', 'Cars', 'Houses'];

categories.forEach((i) => {
  let input = 'Buildings: 1000-1001';
  let re = new RegExp(`${i}: \\d+?([,-]\\d+?)*?$`);
  console.log(re.test(input));

  input = 'Buildings: 1000';
  re = new RegExp(`${i}: \\d+?([,-]\\d+?)*?$`);
  console.log(re.test(input));

  input = 'Buildings: 1000,2002,2003,2034';
  re = new RegExp(`${i}: \\d+?([,-]\\d+?)*?$`);
  console.log(re.test(input));

  input = 'Buildings: 1000,2002';
  re = new RegExp(`${i}: \\d+?([,-]\\d+?)*?$`);
  console.log(re.test(input));
});
```

OUTPUT : Only the first 4 print True because Only the first element of the array is in each of the inputs.

```
true
true
true
true
false
false
...
```

Comment: I think the last `\d*?`should be `\d+?` - otherwise you allow `1000-`.

Comment: @PoulBak good call

Comment: I love this.  But I realize now I have different requirements for each category. Actually, I only really need two regexes. One is what you helped with for numbers/range. The other is one that will allow any text after the identifier as long as it is comma separated (so I can split them to array). How does this need to change for or any comma sep text? I'll just use both as needed.